# Using gsl::span with range-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3, guideline-support-library

I tried a little example to get used to the GSL and range-v3 libraries and I wondered how they could work together. I have this toy example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace ranges;

void example_vector(vector<int> const& v)
{
  ranges::for_each(view::tail(v), [](int x){
    cout << x << ' ';
  });
  cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{
   auto seq = vector<int> { 2,2,2,0,0,2,1,2 };
   example_vector(seq);
}
```

which works. But if I try to use `gsl::span<int>` as a range it leads to an error message. The compiler tells me that `span` does not fullfill the view concept.

```
#include <gsl.h>

// ...

void example_span(gsl::span<const int> v)
{
  ranges::for_each(view::tail(v), [](int x){
    cout << x << ' ';
  });
  cout << '\n';
}
```

Compiler message:

```
note: candidate template ignored: disabled by 'enable_if'
      [with Rng = gsl::span<const int, -1> &, Rest = <>, _concept_requires_123 = 42]
                    CONCEPT_REQUIRES_(ViewConcept<Rng, Rest...>())>
```

But in my understanding it should since a `span` *is* a particular view and even has `begin()` and `end()` iterators (of the same type).

- Wouldn't it be cool if they work together being composable or are
  there any reasons for both to be not compatible?
- I think this is an issue which comes from the strong "concept" usage
  in range-v3. Does it get automatically solved if some other sort of
  concept feature is supported by the language?
- I assume `span` currently needs some adaption if I would like to
  use both libraries together in some piece of (non-industrial) software. What
  should I change to make these work together? (if it is a good idea at all)
- That also leads me ultimately to the question of "What has a class to
  fullfill to work with `range-v3`?" Is inheritance from facades,
  adaptors or such the only way to tell the compiler currently about these conceptional requirements?

Comment: Check out the gsl github issues page. There are a lot of problems with the iterators right now, and they're going to be completely rewritten. IMO it's not in a production ready state right now.

Comment: Can you point to an issue which is directly associated with my problem? I went through the ~40 issues but maybe i did not understand everything ;^). I cant even get the iterators working with any function of range-v3.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in general there are a lot of problems, not that there was a solution there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `View` concept in range-v3 (and the ranges TS, for that matter) requires a type `R` to satisfy both the `Range` concept -- `begin(r)` and `end(r)` delimit an iterator range -- and the `Semiregular` concept -- `R` must be copy/move constructible copy/move assignable, and default constructible. The iterator and sentinel types of a `Range` (what `begin` and `end` return) must also be `Semiregular` (amongst other requirements).

The `span` family doesn't satisfy the `View` concept since `span`s are not default constructible in some cases, and their iterators are not default constructible in any cases. Since even Standard C++ requires default construction for Forward iterators, the current `span` iterators conform to neither the Ranges TS, range-v3, nor Standard C++.

That said, the changes necessary to meet all these families of requirements [are minimal and straight-forward](https://github.com/CaseyCarter/GSL/tree/span_range_v3).

### 20161207 Update:

range-v3 now contains an implementation of `span` that does properly model the `View`/`Range` concepts.

### 20170128 Update:

`gsl::span` now has default constructible iterators. Consequently, spans are now usable with range-v3. Spans with dynamic extent (e.g., `gsl::span<int>`) model the `Range` & `View` concepts, spans with *static* extent (e.g., `gsl::span<int, 42>`) model only `Range` since they do not meet `View`'s requirement for default construction.

Comment: Thank you for this insight and repository!